# warning when view is obtained with its tag

Tags: ios

I have made a custom scrollview newscrollview and added it as a subview to the cell.
I am getting the following warning in the statement

```
newsScrollView=(UIScrollView)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:4];
```

The warning say's incompatible pointer types assigning newscrollview*_strong from uiscrollview.
I tried changing the uiscrollview to newsrollview but then the warning changes to error
thanks in advance

Comment: NickLH, correcting the code sample invalidated the question!

Comment: I've restored the original code sample.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `*`character in your typecast. It should be like this: `newsScrollView=(UIScrollView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:4];`